# Using \toks registers

Tags: tex-core, programming, token-lists

I was reading this tutorial for TeX programming:

http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf

recommended in the 2-nd answer here: [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming)

It says:

> `\toks<number>` There are also 255 token registers which can be thought
>   of as special string variables. Of course, every macro assignment
>   `\def\macro{ content }` is also some kind of string variable, but token
>   registers are special: their contents won’t be expanded when used with
>   `\the\toks` number . This can be used for fine grained expansion
>   control, see Section 2.3 below.

But no examples of using `\toks` registers. What does he mean: "special string variables"? For 2 previous kinds of registers I could assign the value:

```
\count0=12
\dimen0=1.102pt
```

And print it:

```
Value1: \the\count0
Value2: \the\dimen0
```

But I don't understand, how to use `\toks`.

Comment: Good question. My very limited (and probably wrong) understanding is that you store tokens into a token register with `\toks<n>={nearly arbitrary stuff goes here}` and then `\the\toks<n>` grabs the stored tokens and hands them off directly to TeX's stomach.

Comment: The assertion "2. The contents of token registers will never be expanded" is false. It's not expanded when `\the\toks<number>` is used in the replacement text of an `\edef` (or `\xdef`).

Comment: @kahen No; `\the\toks<n>` delivers the contents of the register to the input stream and expansion takes place normally (except in an `\edef`, where the expansion will take place when the `\edef`ed macro will be used).

Comment: @kahen Ahh, yes. He doesn't say, that the string must be enclosed in figure brackets to be assigned to \toks register. Now I got it working.

Comment: TeX has **256** registers called `\toks0` to `\toks255`. The same goes for `\count`, `\dimen`, `\skip`, and `\muskip` registers (pg. 117 of *The TeXbook*). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A token register is very similar to a macro with no arguments, but there are differences in syntax and expansion rules.

Using the plain and latex definition of `\toks@` for `\toks 0`  you can store the tokens `abc` via

```
\toks@{abc}
```

or

```
\def\tmp{abc}
```

Note that a macro has a specific command to set the macro (`\def` or wrappers around that such as `\newcommand`) but token registers just use the register name followed by a *balanced* text group.

Conversely unlike macros which expand just by referencing their name, token registers, like other registers, are not expandable and  their contents are accessed by expanding `\the`.

So

```
\the\toks@
```

and

```
\tmp
```

each expand to `abc`.

Apart from these syntactic differences the expansion of token registers differs from macros in two important ways.

1. expansion in `\edef` and other expansion only contexts is limited to one level:

   ```
   \def\tmp{aaa}

   \def\tmpb{xx \tmp}

   \toks@{xx \tmp}

   \edef\A{\tmpb}

   \edef\B{\the\toks@}
   ```

   Now `\tmpb` and `\toks@` contain the same token list `xx \tmp` but `\A` is defined by fully expanding expandable tokens and so has defnition `xx aaa` but the tokens returned by `\the` are not further expanded in the `\edef` and so `\B` has definition `xx \tmp`
2. The second difference is that as token registers do not have arguments `#` does not need to be (and is not) special when defining or expanding the register.

   ```
   \toks@{#1}
   ```

   is just a token register consisting of a list of two tokens `#` and `1`.

This is put to use in LaTeX's `\g@addto@macro` macro.

```
\g@addto@macro@\foo{abc}
```

is supposed to add `abc` to the end of the current definition of `\foo`.

A simple (and if I recall correctly original) definition could be

```
\makeatletter

\gdef\foo{123}

\def\gaA#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\gaA\foo{abc}

\show\foo
```

That works fine and shows the definition as `123abc`. However try

```
\gaA\foo{#}
```

and you get

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \foo.
```

However we can use the fact that `#` isn't special in a toks register and that the register contents are only expanded once

```
\long\def\g@addto@macro#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \toks@\expandafter{#1#2}%
    \xdef#1{\the\toks@}%
  \endgroup}
```

First the `\toks@` register is defined to contain the expansion of the macro passed in the first argument, followed by the contents of the second argument. `#` is safe to use in a toks assignment.  Then the macro is globally defined to be the expansion of `\thetoks` which is exactly the contents of `\toks@` with no further expansion, even if that contains `#` tokens:

```
\makeatletter

\gdef\foo{123}

\g@addto@macro\foo{abc}

\show\foo

\g@addto@macro\foo{#}

\show\foo
```

produces

```
> \foo=macro:
->123abc.
l.7 \show\foo
             
? 
> \foo=macro:
->123abc##.
l.11 \show\foo
```

where `#` has been added as intended (only one `#` has been added, the doubled `##` is an artefact of using `\show`).

Comment: The fact that `#` is not special makes toks registers particularly valuable for saving "metacode", i.e. code that is involved in the generation of more code, rather than execution.  Macro definitions, *parts* of macro definitions, and so on, as opposed to things that need to be expanded as-is.  By contrast, the expansion-inhibiting property doesn't seem to be as big a deal after eTeX's `\unexpanded`.  (This is addressed more to the audience, of course.)

Comment: What does the @ symbol after the register name mean? It is not mentioned in the book. I googled, but in vain.

Comment: @user4035 -- the `@` symbol in a command name means that this is an "internal" command, and to use it, it must either be within the scope of `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`, or in a `.sty` file where it is by default assumed to be of type "letter".

Comment: @user4035 it's not _after_ the name it is the command name `toks@` (which is defined in latext o mean token register 0)

Comment: @schtandard thanks:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No problem. Thanks for the nice answer.