# Difference between counters and tokens in TeX

Tags: tex-core, counters, token

This is my first question here on TeXSE, and my second question on the StackExchange community. I am reading [Notes on Programming in TeX](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf) by Dr. Christian Feuersänger as part of a general introduction to TeX; I've been using  LaTeX for about a year, and I want to learn in general terms how the TeX system works, i.e. macros, counters, groups, etc. Indeed, after this document I plan to read [TeX for the Impatient](http://tug.ctan.org/info/impatient/book.pdf) for a more thorough introduction to the system.

Subsections 2.1 through 2.4 from the Notes briefly discuss macros, counters and tokens, but I don't quite understand what is the difference between a *counter* and a *token*. Counters can store an integer value, and can be incremented/decremented by `x` with the syntax `\advance\count0 by x`, where `\count0` is a previously defined counter. What does each do? How does TeX understand each one? Which purposes do both serve?

Thanks

#### Edit:

Thanks for the answers. Relating to the one from Phelype Oleinik, sorry, what I meant with *tokens* is instead *registers*. Feuersänger says the following regarding registers:

> There are also 255 token registers which can be thought of as special string variables.
> Of course, every macro assignment `\def\macro{content}` is also some kind of string variable,
> but token registers are special: their contents won't be expanded when used with `\the\toks<number>`.
> This can be used for fine grained expansion control, see Section 2.3 below (p. 3).

Further, he gives the example

```
\toks0={abc}%
\toks1={DEF}%
The value is now \the\toks0 \the\toks1.
```

A counter cannot clearly store the literals `abc`, but what is then the difference between *registers* and *macros*, when one uses a macro to store some control sequence, i. e. just a plain word? Both expand to their content, right?

Comment: Tokens and counters are completely different things. A counter is like an integer variable in other programming languages, as you already said.  A token is any single "thing" seen by TeX (roughly speaking).  For example, the line `\advance\count0 by x` contains the 8 tokens: `\advance`, `\count`, `0`, `<space>`, `b`, `y`, `<space>`, `x`.  Other than that, I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: The concept of token relates to how information is *digested* by TeX.  In the simplest conceptualization, digestion of the input stream of a document occurs one byte at a time, except for *control sequences*, which are sequences of bytes that begin with an *escape character* byte of *category code* 0 (the `\ ` byte is the default escape character).  This is why multi-byte entities such as `\advance` and `\count` constitute single tokens.  Reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/catcode

Comment: From the outside: A concept of tokens is needed because the input stream is a mixture of instructions and material to be typeset: counter tokens store integers; a box can store formatted material; a token stream `t`,`e`,`x`,`t` will typeset `text` in the current font, location, colour; a macro is a token that expands to its definition (itself a token stream, and which may have more macros, and/or  primitives, and/or text) and may or may not take parameters. A group, `{...}`, is local: what happens in the group stays in the group, e.g. font change (unless global actions are occurring).

Comment: Plus, a macro can (re)define itself, which comes in very handy.

Comment: With the update, looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107102/using-toks-registers to me (the registers you are interested in are normally referred to as 'toks')

Comment: Also see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39747/is-toks-necessary-to-define-gaddtomacro-can-token-registers-be-avoided-in-g

Comment: If you are really looking for a "thorough introduction to the system", you should imo just read the TeXbook.

Comment: Thanks Joseph Wright for both suggestions, I will definitively give it a read.  And yes, probably I should read  the _TeXBook_, but I found _TeX by Topic_ by Victor Eijkhout which appears to be what I need.